# Driver ma-config : "your hardware is not supported on this windows version"

Tags: ethernet, drivers, windows-8.1

I'm not sure if it's the right place place to ask for this but well, I don't find the answer anywhere so I try here.

To be simple I'll describe my situation :

My PC was running under Win 8.1 x64 and I needed the pro version for some reason.
So I get the pro version and overwrite the old version.

So my PC is now running on a Windows 8.1 x64 pro.

One of the first thing I went through was the installation of the drivers.
I went on http://www.ma-config.com/en (for those who knows) to get my drivers.

Almost everything was perfect except.. The ethernet controller (and PCI device/ SM bus controller).
I need my Ethernet Controller to work so I tried to download the driver they were advicing me but I got this error : "your hardware is not supported on this windows version".

Is that because I'm on windows pro now?

This is the driver I'm trying to install : 
Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (BigFoot Networks Killer 2100/E2100/Xeno Pro)

I had an image to show but I don't have enough reputation.

PS: I tried to go on the MSI site (my PC is an MSI) but their is the same problem.

EDIT : My PC is an MSI Ge60 2oe

Comment: I suggest you download drivers only from their official web sites. The site you mentioned is not such a site, and you have no guarantee that the software you install from it is not malicious, or even that it's functional.

Comment: It's was what I did at the first time, but then I had even no wi-fi connection and no ethernet.. But I tried again and.. Surprise it works !
Don't know why their driver wasn't working at the first use but thank you for your answer !